# Adding request limit to Sharepoint/Office 365 API List search

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

I have a url I am using to query a list in Sharepoint formatted as below.

```
http://sites/sites/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle%example%/items?$select=Email/EMail&$expand=Email
```

Because my list has over 100 items, I would like to add a `$top=1000` to get all of the items.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add this to my query.

Is this possible or do I have to rework something?

Comment: Nevermind, I added the & sign and it is working

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to fetch the 1000 items using `$top`.

Use something like below:

```
 https://domain/sites/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('example')/items?$select=Email/EMail&$expand=Email&$top=1000
```

Also, I noticed in URL, you have used:

```
/lists/getbytitle%example%/
```

Is it working correctly?

If Not, it should be like :

```
/lists/getbytitle('example')
```

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If Yes, please upvote(^) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).